# Powershell import to SQL Server: quotation error

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to import data from an API into SQL Server table using Powershell.

I have a variable such as $staffName and 99% of the time it imports just fine but if I get a name such as "O'Connor" it gives a single quotation mark error.

```
foreach($s in $staffs) {
$InsertStaffResults = @"
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ImportStaffTable]([staffID],[staffName])
VALUES ('$staffId','$staffname')
"@
    [int]$staffId = $s.id
    $staffname = $s.lastName
    Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $InsertStaffResults 
}
```

Just curious how to get around that. Tried changing the quotation marks and other identifier properties to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To escape single quotes you need to double them.

Try

```
$staffname = $s.lastName -replace "'", "''"
```